# Is there a maximum number of tasks that should be in a Celery TaskSet?

Tags: task, celery

I have mullions of tasks that I need to run. Is there a maximum number of tasks that I should add to a single TaskSet?

I'm thinking about chunking the millions of tasks into TaskSets that have, say 10k tasks each, because it feels right, but maybe there is absolutely no reason for this.

Anybody have any feelings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a bad idea.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/uGbue_4z2xY) you can find a short discussion about the same topic.

Although issue [1078](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1078) has been closed, the issue is still actual. I'd recommend to either use smaller sets or to group them into other GroupResults not larger than 50-70 items in each.

Comment: Wow, so I've been doing this wrong for a while. Thanks for dropping some knowledge on this!